# How to execute function after the inner frame has been loaded?

Tags: iframe

I have this problem,

1. I have an html that contains an inner frame.
2. I have a jquery statement that contains function that will execute after the whole page has been rendered like this:

   $(window).ready(function(){
   //statements here
   });
3. Using the function above I want to check if the inner frame has already been rendered. That is I want to check if the inner frame has already load the inner page and displayed the inner page COMPLETELY. It has a similar effect with `$(window).ready();`

So my question is,

1. How do i code it? Because i already tried this way `$("_iframe id_").ready(_function here for checking_);` and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Ir's a programming question, not a web hosting question. Expect answers ;)

Comment: Is it cross domain? If not you can create a setTimeout loop the continues querying the iframe's document to see if the document.body is available.  Wrap that in a try catch and once the document.body appears in the iframe attach to the bodys onload the function you want to execute.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE INFO!!! that's a good idea actually :D I will try it right a way :D

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$('#iframe').load(function() {
  // Foo.    
});
```

Comment: Hmm, it should. Try using `$(document).ready(...` instead of `$(window).ready(...` and see if that works.

Comment: `$(window).ready()` executes after all the data of the web page is visible on the screen. I usually place this code before the `<\body>` tag so I want a similar result when I check for the rendering of the inner frame (and without explicitly coding the inner frame)